# Как правильно сказать: «о любви» или «про любовь»?

Tags: грамотная-речь, предлоги

Как правильно сказать, исходя из последних пертурбаций в русском языке, и почему?

Comment: Интересно, о каких последних ПЕРТУРБАЦИЯХ в русском языке Вы говорите?

Comment: Наташа Ростова никогда бы не читала книги "про любовь", потому что "Любовь" - это понятие возвышенное. А сейчас разговаривают не о чём-то, а про что-то.

Comment: Потому и "переТРУБАция", а не "Перетурбация" звучит в вопросе.

Comment: Если человек малограмотный, надо же ему как-то жить и говорить) Учить таких - нету денег и желания у государства российского. Поэтому существуют специальные литература, кинематограф и другие виды искуйства для не очень образованных людей. Сериалы про войну, любовь, жизнь и смерть - чего еще человеку нужно, чтобы просто расслабиться на диване после работы.

Comment: А фильм "Еще раз про любовь" из той же серии?

Comment: В названии - злая ирония. Фильм очень проблемный, о борьбе с ханжеством, как мне помнится... Собственно *о любви* там нет разговора, все крутится вокруг мнений посторонних граждан об интимной связи молодых людей.

Comment: Ну, дорогие мои, это уже сказываются результаты введения ЕГЭ. Так сказать, выросло поколение сценаристов и режиссёров, которых не учили русскому литературному языку и эпистолярному жанру, а тупо натаскивали на сдачу тестов ЕГЭ и общению с помощью SMS на так называемом "йазыге падонкафф". То есть, авторы фильма специально  разговаривали на языке, понятном для продвинутой молодёжи, завоёвывая тем самым популярность и "уважуху". А скорее всего, они действительно на нормальном русском языке уже и не умеют разговаривать. В общем, молодёжь стремится к лексикону Люси-людоедки.

Comment: Фильм "Ещё раз про любовь" снят в 1968 году. И причем тут ЕГЭ?

Comment: Сценарист (и автор пьесы, которую с успехом ставили в театрах страны)) - Эдвард Радзинский. Вы его сравниваете с Элочкой-людоедочкой? (И причем тут Люся?)

Comment: В русском языке употребляется предлог о, в украинском нет такого предлога, употребляется только про. Таким образом, про в русском - это просто украиницизм, давно проникший в русскую речь и воспринимающийся как разговорная форма.

Comment: Прежде чем принижать "про", вспомните, у Лермонтова: Чтоб всю ночь, весь день, мой слух лелея,
Про любовь мне сладкий голос пел

Comment: @ВладимирЧерняк Никто и не принижает "про" — мы разбираемся, как правильно, лучше **сегодня** (180 лет все-таки прошло). Кстати, есть "про" и у других, не менее известных авторов (по времени — еще раньше, чем у Лермонтова). _Но давно душа неясно Про любовь шепнула ей: Витязь юный и прекрасный Был давно ей всех милей._ [М. Н. Загоскин. Аскольдова могила (1833)] _Неправду сказали ей и подруги ее про любовь: видно, они сами не знали ее._ [И. И. Лажечников. Басурман (1838)]

Answer (score 7):

Предлог про  раньше являлся  разговорным синонимом предлога о. Почему? Не знаю, так сложилось. Но постепенно стал употребляться наравне с предлогом О. В словаре Ожегова, Шведовой уже упоминания о разговорности нет. Хотя, на мой взгляд, она все же сохраняется. И на уроке я скажу: стихотворение о любви, а не про любовь.  А в неофициальной обстановке возможно и про: пойду почитаю что-нибудь про любовь...

Comment: Почему-то исчезли все значки для форматирования: не могу ни наклон поменять, ни жирность.

Comment: Выделить слово можно, если добавить по бокам слова или фразы звёздочки(*)

1 * - курсив  
2 * - жирный текст  
3 * - жирный курсив

Comment: >Почему-то исчезли все значки для форматирования: не могу ни наклон поменять, ни жирность.   
  
Для начала убедитесь, что это постоянная ситуация.  раньше рекомендовал бы перезагрузить компьютер, сейчас даже боюсь что-то советовать. С другого браузера разве зайти.

Comment: Спасибо, уже не актуально, видимо, перезагрузка все-таки помогла.

Answer (score 3):

Если говорить о самых общих значениях предлогов О и ПРО по отношению к предмету, то видится следующее различие в их использовании. Употребляя предлог О с общим значением направленности ВОКРУГ предмета, мы предполагаем его сложность, замкнутость и невозможность полного раскрытия. Употребляя предлог ПРО, мы направляем действие СКВОЗЬ предмет, считая его структуру ясной и доступной для понимания и изложения.  Соответственно, пользователь языка может выбрать ту или иную форму предлога в зависимости от ситуации: говорит ли он о частной стороне любви, или предполагает философское раскрытие этой темы.

Comment: Целиком и полностью согласен. Вопрос о любви в настоящее время низводится к банальному сексу, который, кстати, тоже низведён к банальному спариванию. Потому и говорят не о любви, а про любовь и про секс. Для молодёжи разве есть что-то неизведанного в любви, требующего философского подхода к вопросу взаимоотношения полов?

Comment: >Вопрос о любви в настоящее время низводится (...)

"Грубый век, грубые нравы, романтизьму нет" (с) :-)

Это только у тех, у кого толку не хватает на красивые, романтические отношения.

Comment: @Алексей Радч..., "Декамерон" Бокачо почитайте. Раньше секса было не меньше, если не больше, а вот женитьба по любви в патриархальном обществе - это уже скорее исключение, чем правило, особенно для девушек.

Answer (score 2):

Когда-то давно читала, что в английском языке раньше были падежи, но потом они пропали и были заменены предлогами. В частности из-за того, что падежи нужно различать по окончаниям, которые "проглатываются" при разговоре. Может, тут такая же тенденция? Ведь "про" не требует дательного падежа, слово "любовь" остается неизменным.

Что касается вопроса. Мне "про" ухо не режет, воспринимается совершенно спокойно.

Comment: >...в английском языке раньше были падежи, но потом они пропали и были заменены предлогами.  
  
Если не придираться к формулировке, то да.   

>...из-за того, что падежи нужно различать по окончаниям, которые "проглатываются" при разговоре.  
  
Нет. Там ряд причин, одна из них та, что в момент номаннского завоевания (не путать с французским) побежденные и победители говорили на близких языках германской группы, сильно отличающихся как раз падежными окончаниями. Они и первую очередь и отмерли, потребовав, кстати, жесткой структуры предложения и порядка члеов в нем. К русскому неприменимо.